# mongodb how to get max value of each "group with the same key"

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection:

```
{'name':'ada','updateTime':'2016-11-25'}
{'name':'bob','updateTime':'2016-11-25'}
{'name':'ada','updateTime':'2016-11-20'}
{'name':'bob','updateTime':'2016-11-20'}
{'name':'ada','updateTime':'2016-11-15'}
{'name':'bob','updateTime':'2016-11-15'}
...
```

if I want the result is, the max value of 'updateTime' of the same 'name':

```
{'name':'ada','updateTime':'2016-11-25'}
{'name':'bob','updateTime':'2016-11-25'}
...
```

or finaly get a python dict:

```
{'ada':'2016-11-25','bob':'2016-11-25',...}
```

**How to do it most effective?**

I do it now in python is:

```
for name in db.collection.distinct('name'):
    result[name]=db.collection.find({'name':name}).sort('updateTime',-1)[0]
```

is it do 'find' too many times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **MongoDB** there is an option for finding max value with **$max** operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $group:{
         "_id":"$name",
         updateTime:{
            $max:"$updateTime"
         }
      }
   }
])
```

With above query below my output.

```
{
    "_id" : "bob",
    "updateTime" : "2016-11-25"
}
{
    "_id" : "ada",
    "updateTime" : "2016-11-25"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do this in a single query with aggregation :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $sort:{
         updateTime:-1
      }
   },
   {
      $group:{
         "_id":"$name",
         updateTime:{
            $first:"$updateTime"
         }
      }
   }
])
```

this will return

```
{ "_id" : "bob", "updateTime" : "2016-11-25" }
{ "_id" : "ada", "updateTime" : "2016-11-25" }
```

try it online: [mongoplayground.net/p/QZ01RSDneyR](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QZ01RSDneyR)