# Finding the max date of each id from millions of data in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

I have a collection as below and I need to find the max action time of the products in the list whose product_id is given.

In addition, since there are millions of data, it should be as stabilized as possible. Can you help me?

Example data: If productId is 125 or 126

```
[
  {
    "_id": "object",
    "at": "2022-03-25 05:00:00",
    "productId": 125
  },
  {
    "_id": "object",
    "at": "2022-03-25 04:00:00",
    "productId": 125
  },
  {
    "_id": "object",
    "at": "2022-03-24 12:00:00",
    "productId": 126
  },
  {
    "_id": "object",
    "at": "2022-03-25 08:00:00",
    "productId": 127
  }
]
```

Example output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "object",
    "productId": 125
    "at": "2022-03-25 05:00:00"
  },
  {
    "_id": "object",
    "productId": 126,
    "at": "2022-03-24 12:00:00"
  }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mongodb how to get max value of each "group with the same key"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40804317/mongodb-how-to-get-max-value-of-each-group-with-the-same-key)

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me because when I sort it says you have exceeded the data limit to sort and when I group it gives a timeout. Because I have a lot of data.

Comment: Are you applying the `productId` filter before sorting or grouping

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to get your desired output.

N.B.:  There should be an index on `"productId"`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "productId": {
        "$in": [125, 126]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$productId",
      "newRoot": {
        "$top": {
          "sortBy": {
            "at": -1
          },
          "output": "$$ROOT"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {"$replaceWith": "$newRoot"}
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/G5GS8Xtzovk).

Comment: Uncaught exception: Error: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "unknown group operator '$top'",
 "code" : 15952,
 "codeName" : "Location15952"
} : aggregate failed :

Comment: @rickhg12hs included a link to the playground demonstrating that the solution works. This is probably a version mismatch, but you haven't provided any version specifics or constraints in your question for consideration Mehmet Serkan Ekinci. If such constraints exist then should provide them as part of the question

Comment: @MehmetSerkanEkinci What version of the MongoDB server are you running?  Is server-side javascript enabled?